# How to make a UserControl with a Collection that can be edited at design time?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms, user-controls

I'm making a class called `PanelsList` that is basically a `TabControl` without the headers on the top, so the pages can only be changed programmatically. Each "tab" will be and instance of a class called `PanelsListItem` that derives from `Panel`. I also made a class `PanelsListItemCollection` that implements `ICollection` and `ICollection<PanelsListItem>`. So I added the following to my `PanelsList`:

```
    private PanelsListItemCollection _Items;

    public PanelsListItemCollection Items
    {
        get { return _Items; }
        set { SetItems(value); }
    }

    private void SetItems(PanelsListItemCollection value)
    {
        if (_Items != value)
        {
            if (_Items != null) _Items.PanelsList= null;
            _Items = value;
            if (_Items != null) _Items.PanelsList= this;
        }
    }
```

I assumed that after building and adding a `PanelsList` to my form I would be able to edit the `PanelsListItemCollection` on design time. But when I click on the "..." button on the property `Items` in the *Proeprties* editor, the *Object Collection Editor* opens but the *Add* and *Remove* buttons are disabled.

When I added a property `List<Control> Stuff { get; set; }` to my `PanelsList` I could add and remove controls from `Stuff` on design time. I wonder if I need to implement `IList` instead of `ICollection`?

**Edit:** I just tried implementing also `IList<PanelsListItem>` but it didn't fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for a collection to be automatically supported by the designer, it must implement the non-generic `IList` interface - `IList<T>` will not automatically work. This is because the default collection editor relies on knowing the index of each item. The other requirement for compatibility with the designer (which your code already satisfies) is that the property exposing your collection must have both `get` and `set` methods; the designer makes a temporary copy of your collection during editing and then assigns it to the property when the user clicks OK.

If the default is not good enough, you can implement your own collection editor by extending the `UITypeEditor` class (in the `System.Drawing.Design` namespace) and decorating the property in your code with the `EditorAttribute`, e.g.

```
[Editor(typeof(MyCustomCollectionEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))] 
public PanelsListItemCollection Items { /* ... */ }
```

You can also extend the existing `CollectionEditor` class, but the class only exposes very limited functionality to derived classes.